# What kind of jquery/css script positions a button "fixed", but also reacts to webpage scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, social-networking

Sorry that question is a bit wishy washy. Let me explain the effect I'm after:

Instead of just using position:fixed on a button that is left:0 and top:50%, I've seen effects on the web where when the user scrolls down, the button (and rest of the page heads upwards), but the button eases back into it's original fixed position. So it's much more noticeable than just a css fixed item.

I'm having a real hard time googling this effect. I can't remember what sites I've seen it on but it usually contains social/share buttons when scrolling down an article.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is a *floating panel.* http://www.jquery4u.com/menus/floating-message-plugins/

Comment: Thank you for this script. This is very similar and I'm glad I now have it as a resource, however the answer below is what I meant. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fairly simple jQuery code snippet taken directly from here: http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/ (not my code)

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Of course, change `#sidebar` to match your button.

Comment: Spot on! This is what I was after. An element that comes back and chases you down the page!